# Why code after return statement executing inside for-in loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

my variable look like this

```
var widgets2 = [{
    id: "1",
    title: 'title',
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: 'title2',
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: 'title3',
    children: [{
      id: "4",
      title: 'title4',
      children: [],
    }, {
      id: "5",
      title: 'title5',
      children: [],
      children: [{
          id: "6",
          title: 'title6',
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: "7",
          title: 'title7',
          children: [],
        }
      ]
    }],
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    title: 'title9',
    children: [],
  }
]
```

The function code look like this

```
function findTheKey(id,widget){
 let newObj=[...widget];
    for(var key in newObj){
        if(newObj[key]['id']==id){
        console.log(newObj[key])
        return newObj[key];
        }
        console.log("came here")
        if(newObj[key].hasOwnProperty("children")){
         findTheKey(id,newObj[key].children);
        }
    }
}
```

When the called the function using following code

```
var result=findTheKey(4,widgets2);
console.log(result)
```

The result look like this

```
{id: "4", title: "title4", children: Array(0)}
 came here
```

That means even after executing return statement, console.log getting executed, any help will be highly appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: The `return` statement only gets executed if the `if` statement is true

Comment: you have a for loop that can be executed many times before the conditional return statement may be reached

Comment: Your object with id 4 is nested within a children key. Your loop is checking for exactly this and when it is true (your second if statement) you are calling the `findTheKey` method again with the children array. This is what happens -> console.log('came here') -> calling method with children array again -> found the ID and returns.

Comment: @TobiasBoertz, is there a way to get the desired result with minor modification. What i am expecting out of  the function is to return me the the object with id 4.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a recursive function, the return does not have the effect you expect, you need a variable outside the recursive function to keep the current state of what you want to find.

See the snippet below for example:

```js
var widgets2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "title",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "title2",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "title3",
    children: [
      {
        id: "4",
        title: "title4",
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        title: "title5",
        children: [],
        children: [
          {
            id: "6",
            title: "title6",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "7",
            title: "title7",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    title: "title9",
    children: [],
  },
];

let found;
function findTheKey(id, widget) {
  let newObj = [...widget];
  for (var key in newObj) {
    if (newObj[key]["id"] == id) {
      found = newObj[key];
      break;
    }
    if (newObj[key].hasOwnProperty("children")) {
      findTheKey(id, newObj[key].children);
    }
  }
  return found;
}

var result = findTheKey(4, widgets2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: how to make sure that i will get the  desired result in "result" variable ?
kind of stuck in it for long time.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you could for example use a variable that is outside the recursive function in order for you to check when the recursion can stop.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question for this, but since you asked for it in the comments, here is what I propose.

```
function findTheKey(id, widget) {
  const newObj = [...widget];
  for (const key in newObj) {
    if (newObj[key]["id"] === `${id}`) {
        return newObj[key];
    }
    if (newObj[key].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        /* Use the result of the recursive function */
        const foundObject = findTheKey(id, newObj[key].children);
        if(foundObject) return foundObject;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```